# Interval of convergence of series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to find the interval of convergence of 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(nx)^n}{n!}$$
I tried letting $a_n=\frac{(nx)^n}{n!}$ and considered:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(x(n+1))^{n+1}n!}{(n+1)!(xn)^n}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x}{n+1}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x}{n+1}\frac{1}{\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}}$$
Not really sure how to show it, but wouldn't 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=1$$
and 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x}{n+1}=0$$
which means the interval of convergence is infinite? I am not too confidant on this reasoning though and some help would be appreciated

Comment: why not cancel out (n+1)^n+1 with n+1 in the denominator?

Comment: Your first limit is incorrect. Write the limit expression as ${1\over n+1}(n/ (n+1))^n$. Cancel the $n+1$'s and then use the fact that $(n/(n+1))^n$ tends to $1/e$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Ok, will try this, I was considering root test, but was unsure of how to deal with the factorial

Comment: Sorry. Ratio is probably better.

Comment: On a related note, see [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remember the absolute values when using the ratio test, so you should be computing the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$. Then your computation is good to this point:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|\frac{x}{n+1}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^n}\right|$$

You can simplify this to

$\begin{align} &=\lim_{n \to \infty}|x|\frac{(n+1)^{n}}{n^n}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}|x|\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}|x|\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\\
&=e|x|\end{align}$